# Rings of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, continuity, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Recently I have been studying Rings of real-valued continuous functions. I came up with the following question that I am not able to answer. Please help me.

Does there exist a topological space $X$ and a point $x_{0} \in X$ such that $C(X) - (M_{x_{0}} \cup T)$ is countably infinite? (here, $M_{x_{0}} = \{f \in C(X) \mid f(x_{0}) = 0\}$ and $T$ is the set of all constant functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: If $f$ is s function in that set, isn't $\lambda f$ there as well, for any $0\ne\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If $f$ is in your set, with $f(x_0)=a$, then $f(x)+b$ is in your set for any $b\neq -a$.

Comment: Yes, I got it, thank you.